# Prove that : $a,b,c\in\mathbb{Z}$ then : $abc\equiv 0\pmod{3} \implies a^{3}+b^{3}+c^{3}\equiv 0\pmod{9}$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Prove that :

$a,b,c\in\mathbb{Z}$ then :

$$abc\equiv 0\pmod{3} \implies a^{3}+b^{3}+c^{3}\equiv 0\pmod{9}$$

My try :

Let $a\not\equiv 0\pmod{3}$

Then :

$$a\equiv 1,2\pmod{3}$$

So :

$$a^{3}\equiv ±1\pmod{9}$$

Similarly :

$$b^{3}\equiv ±1\pmod{9}$$

$$c^{3}\equiv ±1\pmod{9}$$

$$\implies a^{3}+b^{3}+c^{3}\equiv 0\pmod{9}$$

Is my solution correct ??

And we can generalized or no ?

$$abc\equiv 0\pmod{3} \iff a^{3}+b^{3}+c^{3}\equiv 0\pmod{9}$$

Comment: It is not true. Take $a=3,b=1,c=1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed in the comments , the equivalence is false but it's converse is always true . $$a^3+b^3+c^3 \equiv 0 \mod9\implies abc\equiv 0\mod3$$

Since a cube can be written as $x^3\equiv 0,1,8 \mod 9$  , the only way to add these residues to be divisible by $9$ is $(0,0,0)$ and $(0,1,8)$ and their permutations.

In either the case we get at least one cube divisible by $9$ implying that the number is divisible by $3$ and the conclusion follows.

---

The problem with your attempt is that you assumed $$a^3 \equiv b^3\equiv c^3 \equiv \pm 1\mod 9$$  which implies that $3\not\mid a,b,c$ , which means that $abc\equiv 0\mod 3$ is false.

Comment: very nice explain! Do you have a another method to prove original implications !!

Comment: @EllenEllen As already explained above  , the original equivalence is in fact false . Could you tell from where have you taken  this question ?